# Filter Yaml documents by a key using yq

Tags: kubernetes-helm, yq

I would like to filter a list of document by a specific key.

I have the output of helm template which is huge I just want to see where `kind: Pod`.

Answer (score 1):

```
helm template . | yq 'select(.kind == "Pod")'
```

Reference: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/513#issuecomment-847883445

Comment: `. |` is redundant. Just `select(.kind == "Pod")`